# check the content of iFrame and respond using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a form, which when submitted appends a loader image. The response of the form is shown on an iFrame that is on the page. I am looking to fadeout the loader image once the iframe has got the necessary content in it, after a certain delay period.

I am VERY new to jQuery, so my apologies for the crude understanding of the code I am not sure what is wrong or right with the below code. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Code here:

```
$(function() {

    $(".submitButton").click(function() {

         $('#mainDiv').append('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loaderIcon" id="loaderIcon" alt="Loading..." />');

     });

     if($('#iFrameName').contents().val()!==""){    

         delay(3000);
         $('#mainDiv img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(1000);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//bind an event handler to the `load` event for the iframe
$('#iFrameID').on('load', function () {

    //get the contents of the `body` element in the iframe
    var response = $(this).contents().find('body').html();

    //here you can do what you want with the response variable, for instance you can check for the existance of a specific element
    if (response.filter('#successID').length > 0) {

        //if there is an element in the iframe with the id of `successID` then the loaderIcon will be removed
        $('#loaderIcon').remove();
    }
});
```

Note: `.on()` is new as of jQuery 1.7, if you are using an older version of jQuery then I suggest using `.bind()` instead (the syntax is the same in this instance).

Answer (score 0):

In the parent page, add:

```
function hideLoader() {
    $('#loaderIcon').remove();
}
```

If your Iframe response put:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
parent.hideLoader()
</script>
```